# How can I add a <use> to an inline SVG using jQuery (or plain JavaScript if needed)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an inline SVG with  in an HTML5 document, and would like to add  with jQuery (or plain JavaScript if needed).

I know how to add a rect, circle or other form, but I'm not able yet to reuse an existing .

Here is a test on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhoizey/uDVbn/

The SVG:

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <symbol id="piece"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="green" /></symbol>
  <circle cx="70" cy="90" r="20" stroke="blue" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

The JavaScript:

```
// it works!
var rect = $(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect"))
  .attr({
    x: 10,
    y: 30,
    width: 50,
    height: 70,
    stroke: "red",
    fill: "white"
  });
$("svg").append(rect);

// it doesn't work
var newPiece = $(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","use"))
  .attr({
    "xlink:href": "#piece",
    transform: "translate(100, 100)"
  });
$("svg").append(newPiece);
```

I know there is a jQuery SVG plugin, but would like to keep it as light as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to add href attribute is to use setAttributeNS.

```
useElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'href', '#piece');
```